# Is it possible in Soap UI (Free edition) to programatically start a new test case?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, ant, soapui

In Soap UI free edition I have a test case with two steps: Fire a request and read the next line from an input .csv file with the next test case. I do this by utilizing the command `testRunner.gotoStep(0)`.

This is working fine, except it generates a  not-so-intuitive test 'report'.

I found a [blog post](https://softwaretestersforum.blogspot.com/2013/03/generate-junit-style-html-reports-in.html) about generating junit style reports which I have implemented as we are using Ant in our setup.

However, as I only start 1 test case and iterate it many times the generated junit report only shows 1 test case run, and if there is an error (or more), only shows 1 failure.

And now my question:

Is it possible to, either in Groovy code or otherwise, 'restart' a test case or otherwise trigger Soap UI to create a new instance of the same test case so that in my junit report it will show right amount of the actual tests run - corresponding to the amount of input lines in my .csv?

I have tried to play around with the testRunner interface of Soap UI, but it seems rather pointless as it is the same as the command line interface used by Ant.

I know the pro version have some great reporting capabilities, but my question goes on the free version.

Comment: Looks you are running a data driven test. Obviously there is only one test case present in the test suite, so the result has only one test case. If you create a new test case of every row of the data, then you wont be able to leverage data driven test, right?

Comment: Exactly - and, as this is something new in my organisation, I would like to keep my Soap UI project as generic as possible in order to use this technique across multiple projects.

Comment: I would think even if one of the row in the data file fails, you wont be able to run the test against specific row, have to run the test for entire data. So, you may continue to treat it a case and convince your management. Not sure what option you will have.

Comment: What you say is not there even in ReadyAPI which pro software.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to code the solution myself by utilizing the fact I have access to the results in the tear down script of the test suite. I write the information to a xml file which can be read by Ant's `<junitreport>` and use Ant to generate the report and open it in a browser.